# Exclude a class from fired event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has on keyup events being fired if the dynamically generated inputs are modified but i would like to exclude certain classes of input in the table row from the events, I have tried two options and both have failed

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.tg > tbody > tr:not(.pd1)', function() {});
$(document).on('keyup', '.tg > tbody > tr:not(".pd1")', function() {}); //added quotes to pd1 class
```

sugestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of registering the event to tr, use input

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.tg > tbody  input:not(.pd1)', function() {});
```

Answer (score 2):

Arun assumes the class `pd1` is on the input and not the tr like the question suggests. if the class `pd1` is on the `tr` then:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.tg > tbody > tr:not(.pd1) input', function() {});
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks a lot xdumaine, but in my case the pd1 class is for an input